# Inference of frequency of values in a poisson distributed histogram

Tags: poisson-distribution, inference, histogram, frequency

For some data there is a histogram, which has bins with varying sizes. Is it possible to infer the frequency of the values for smaller segments of the bins, favourably with Matlab?

With the attached image of a histogram with varying bins, is it possible to infer the frequency (Proportion of people per one minute interval) for 1-minute bins (travel time)? For example, how many people travel 51 minutes?

For some reasons, I can assume that my data is poisson-distributed. One possible way of inferring the values could possibly be to calculate the poisson distribution from the histogram. But AFAIK, Matlab would need equidistant bins.

I think I have *lost* some information. But just using linear interpolation doesn't seem like the best option, either. E.g. dividing the frequency of a bin through the bin-lenght and using this value for all 1-minute sub-bins.

[image: Sample histogram]

To make matters worse, my real use case has negative time values and bins at the edge of the histogram which extend to infinity, or at least to some unknown value. Is it possible to cope with that, too?

Comment: Could you explain what a "negative time value" means? If it is believed to be an accurate measurement, then obviously your data will not be well-described by any Poisson distribution.

Comment: The time values represent delay can be negative, in my case. (Start before the planned time.) The number of occurences of the negative delay would be positive, though.